# Sharepoint hosted App and Lync integration - Lync API 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api, lync-2013, office365-apps

I have a SharePoint hosted app and need to integrate Lync features into it. I am assuming that Lync client is not installed on target machine. Lync features should work for both On-Premise as well as Lync online.

I have seen UCWA 4.0 but that does not work with SharePoint hosted apps and office 365 apps.

Is there any another API that I can use?